# Notepad++ search for semicolon folled by two digit number and a quotation mark, and replace only semicolon

Tags: regex, replace, notepad++

I want to use Notepad++'s Find/Replace feature to do the following:

**Find:** Semicolon featured by two digits followed by quotation marks (Example: `;25"`)

**Replace:** Replace the semicolon with a colon (Example result: `,25"`)

**What I have so far:** I can find what I want (see above) with the following regex: `;[0-9]{2}"`. However, I am not sure how to properly use the replace function. I know that I can refer with `\1` to the matched group, but this does not solve the task.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this regex mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [**capturing group**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html):

**Find what**:      `;(\d{2}")`
**Replace with**: `,\1`

The `\1` is a [numeric backreference](https://www.regular-expressions.info/replacebackref.html) that holds the value captured by Group 1, and the group is defined with a pair of unescaped parentheses in the pattern.

**Settings & demo**:

[image]

Comment: thanks! i will accept as answer. just a quick followup: i work with a large file and notepad++ seems to have issues. shouldn't the same regex work in UltraEdit?

Comment: @beta Yes, if you set the regex flavor to Perl/PCRE. In the replacement, you may change `\1` to `$1`.